# Price a contingent claim with payoff $(S_{1T}-S_{2T})^+$ at time $T$

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-calculus, sde, geometric-brownian

Two stocks are modelled as follows:
$$dS_{1t}=S_{1t}(\mu_1dt+\sigma_{11}dW_{1t}+\sigma_{12}dW_{2t})$$
$$dS_{2t}=S_{2t}(\mu_2dt+\sigma_{21}dW_{1t}+\sigma_{22}dW_{2t})$$
with $dW_{1t}dW_{2t}=\rho dt$.There is also a money market account $dB_t=rB_tdt$. The task is to compute the price at time $t$ of a contingent claim with payoff $(S_{1T}-S_{2T})^+$ at time $T$ using matringale-based pricing.
My idea was to decompose $(S_{1T}-S_{2T})^+=S_{2T}\left(\frac{S_{1T}}{S_{2T}}-1\right)^+$ and define a process $Z_t=\frac{S_{1t}}{S_{2t}}$. Thus, the price at time $t$ should be $S_{2t}$ times the price of a call option on $Z_t$ with strike $K=1$. So, using Ito's formula:
$$dZ_t=\frac{\partial Z}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial S_1}dS_{1t}+\frac{\partial Z}{\partial S_2}dS_{2t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 Z}{\partial S^2_1}(dS_{1t})^2+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 Z}{\partial S^2_2}(dS_{2t})^2+\frac{\partial^2 Z}{\partial S_1 \partial S_2}dS_{1t}dS_{2t}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{S_{2t}}dS_{1t}-\frac{S_{1t}}{S^2_{2t}}dS_{2t}+\frac{S_{1t}}{S^3_{2t}}(dS_{2t})^2-\frac{1}{S^2_{2t}}dS_{1t}dS_{2t}=$$
$$=Z_t\left((\mu_1-\mu_2)dt+(\sigma_{11}-\sigma_{21})dW_{1t}+(\sigma_{12}-\sigma_{22})dW_{2t}+(\sigma_{21}^2+\sigma_{22}^2+2\rho\sigma_{21}\sigma_{22})dt-(\sigma_{11}\sigma_{21}+\rho\sigma_{11}\sigma_{22}+\rho\sigma_{12}\sigma_{21}+\sigma_{12}\sigma_{22})dt\right)$$
However, nothing cancels out, so it leads me believe that I am on the wrong track. Furthermore, I am not using the money market account given in the task this way. Is there a neat trick for solving this task? Do not really know how to go from there. 
I understand that I can change the measure $d\hat{W}_{it}=dW_{it}+\lambda_idt$ for $i\in{1;2}$ and choose the lambdas to make the drift term of both stocks equal to $r$, but I do not see how this helps to solve the problem. I also see that I can rewrite the system using matrix notation, but, yet again, I do not see how this helps. 
The problems that I have seen before only had one Brownian motion per equation, so I am confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A few ideas (from someone who is a bit rusty to be honest)
1. Typically it's easier to work with independent Brownian motions e.g. find a way to describe $W_2 = aW_1 + bW_3$ where $<W_1, W_3> = 0$
2. Can we find the changes of measure required so that $S_1$ and $S_2$ (when discounted) are martingales?
From there I think it will turn into an easier expectation to take, and I think your approach (similar to Magrabe's formula) is probably a good one

Comment: Please, share if you try your method in some inputs.